# Birt: how to run JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, birt

So I have a script that I would like to run to dynamically format my report. But I don't know what to do with it. Where to I place the .js file and how to I tell birt to run the script after the design phase?

I have found resources on what I can do with scripts but none of them go over how to use them in birt.  Some of them talk about a resource folder but I don't know where this resource folder should go.

can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks a lot. I am running Birt 4.2.2

P.S. Oh and no report designer stuff. I am working in java not the designer.

Comment: which tool you are using to develop birt report and what is the version of birt?

Comment: Sorry I am using BIRT 4.2.2

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figgured it out. you have to add `data.setOnRender(jsStr);` when constructing the report.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
    CellHandle cell = (CellHandle) tabledetail.getCells().get(i);
    DataItemHandle data = designFactory.newDataItem("data_" + cols.get(i));

    data.setResultSetColumn(cols.get(i));

    cell.getContent().add(data);
    String jsStr = "JavaScript goes here.";

    data.setOnRender(jsStr);
}
```